# in order to have a

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "have" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer. should be changed to "has"?

> The usage of renewable energies should be increased in order to **have** a
>   clean environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, it's correct use, but semantically, I would prefer the verb *get*, combined with the comparative form of the adjective:

> The usage of renewable energies should be increased in order to **get** a clean**er** environment.

Reason:
*Have* indicates a *de facto* state: the environment *is* cleaner if you use renewable energies.
*Get* indicates a state that is either *in process or imagined*: the invironment *will become* cleaner if you use renewable energies (but at the moment, you aren't).
In your sentence, the *get* option would work better because you are using the modal verb *should*, which shows that you aren't talking about a state that has been reached yet, but that is imagined will only become a reality if the conditions (use of more clean energies) are fulfilled.